# Error Json Parse Error Start Arrray?

Tags: java, angular, jpa

Tengo un problema al momento de aguardar mi metodo me aparaece este problema estoy manejando JPA en mi backend este es mi codigo de guardado.
Este es mi Dto

```
    @Column("header")
    private String header;
    @Column("rows")
    private String rows;

    public ApiResponseDto editModuleTestDefiniton(InstrumentModuleTestDefinition instrumentModuleTestDefinition) {
        try {
            cassandraOperations.update(instrumentModuleTestDefinition);
        return new ApiResponseDto("Save","Success Edit InstrumentTest");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ApiResponseDto("Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }

    "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
     at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 400] (through reference chain: com.fsa.instqual.domain.InstrumentModuleTestDefinition["header"])"


Y este es mi angular al momento de guardar
this.testSave = {
   'testType': this.typeSend,
   'header': this.headerSend,
   'rows': this.rowsSend,
}
```

y cada vez que doy save y quiero aguardar mis datos aparece siempre el error mencionado Podrian alguien ayudarme a decirme donde esta mi error? recuerden que estoy utilizando un metodo perteneciente de JPA

```
"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 400] (through reference chain: com.fsa.instqual.domain.InstrumentModuleTestDefinition["header"])"
```

Answer (score 0):

El fallo esta aquí:

```
this.testSave = {
  'testType': this.typeSend,
  'header': this.headerSend, //AQUI
  'rows': this.rowsSend,
}
```

El problema es que lo que devuelves no es de tipo `string`. Las funciones `header` y `rows` deben devolver un **string** No un `String` de TS, un tipo `string`, si no le pasas eso, java intenta serializar algo que sería para una clase o para un array como un `String` y casca.

Las funciones en `TypeScript` deberian estar definidas así:

```
public rowsSend():string {
}
public headerSend():string {
}
```

Espero que te lo solucione...

***PD: Obviamente cuando se pasa del front hay que serializar el JSON pasandolo por la funcion JSON.stringify***